# Django,unable to download mp3 files in frontend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My Django app have mp3 file field as mentioned in the below model. I upload mp3 files from admin side. When I send GET request for mp3 files in frontend , it plays in browser but I can't download If I attempt download it results in error as mention below in terminal and download fails

MODELS.PY

```
from django.db import models

class Music(models.Model):
    ...
    track = models.FileField(upload_to='tracks')
```

ERRORS

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\socketserver.py", line 796, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[05/Jun/2020 16:33:37] "GET /media/tracks/Kalimba.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 500 59

Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59832)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

VIEWS.PY

```
class MusicList(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        genre = self.kwargs.get('genre')
        songs = Music.objects.filter(genre=genre)
        serializer = Musicserializer(songs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

SERIALIZERS.PY

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Music


class Musicserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likes_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Music
        exclude = ('like',)

    def get_likes_count(self, instance):
        return instance.like.count()
```

Comment: @ AnoopKGeorge the reason is the varibale is empty (you are calling ```split``` on an empty variable), before calling it check if there is anything in it and also it is good to add your ```view``` to make it easier to spot the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated it. I don't recall using split in any instance of my code

Comment: @ Anoop K George  could you check if this variable ```songs = Music.objects.filter(genre=genre)``` is empty or not